# unpivot result from temporary table

Tags: sql, pivot, field, unpivot

i try to get the result in an unpivot resultset but with more column I've never used this technique.

I got a temporary table.. with many field... but focus on listing below.

```
SELECT 
    u.IDNode_u,
    l.lev_u
from #Slugs
unpivot
(
  IDNode_u  for node       in (IDNodo, IDNodoPadre, [IDNodoPadre-2], [IDNodoPadre-3], [IDNodoPadre-4], [IDNodoPadre-5], [IDNodoPadre-6])
) u
unpivot
(
  lev_u   for level   in (LivelloTop, [LivelloTop-1], [LivelloTop-2], [LivelloTop-3], [LivelloTop-4], [LivelloTop-5], [LivelloTop-6])
) l
```

The query is ok only with the first unpivot, with second add I got error:
"The multi-part identifier "u.IDNodo_u" could not be bound.", but I think is bound to the second unpivot.

Can someone with me some advise?
Alen Italy.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to unpivot is to use `cross apply`:

```
select u.IDNode_u, l.lev_u
from #slugs s cross apply
     (values (IDNodo), (IDNodoPadre), ([IDNodoPadre-2]), ([IDNodoPadre-3]),
             ([IDNodoPadre-4]), ([IDNodoPadre-5]), ([IDNodoPadre-6])
     ) u(IDNode_u) cross apply
     (values (LivelloTop), ([LivelloTop-1]), ([LivelloTop-2]),
             ([LivelloTop-3]), ([LivelloTop-4]), ([LivelloTop-5]),
             ([LivelloTop-6])
     ) l(lev_u);
```

EDIT:

I think you intend:

```
select ul.IDNode_u, ul.lev_u
from #slugs s cross apply
     (values (IDNodo, LivelloTop),
             (IDNodoPadre, [LivelloTop-1]),
             ([IDNodoPadre-2], [LivelloTop-2]),
             ([IDNodoPadre-3], [LivelloTop-3]),
             ([IDNodoPadre-4], [LivelloTop-4]),
             ([IDNodoPadre-5], [LivelloTop-5]),
             ([IDNodoPadre-6], [LivelloTop-6])
     ) ul(IDNode_u, lev_u) ;
```

Comment: I try it but I think I have to use UNPIVOT.... 'cause when I add third fields all explode...100K row...
I have to understand multiple pivot fields return...

Comment: @ACaps . . . Your nested unpivot would do the same thing.  I think you want the edited answer.

Comment: Yes... Gordon you're right.
Thanks for your support!
I've resolve it with your code... unpivot isn't necessary
ALEN